# Generate Array from Google Spreadsheet Data

Tags: google-apps-script

I am trying to use the Google Apps Script API and generate an array from an existing document and the data inside it. I was able to generate one with data directly like this but I need to generate one dynamically from sheet data.

```
var myStringArray = ["Q #1","Q #2","Q #3"];
```

I tried this but failed...

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('0AvDqITxPHOGndENaZGJRTEkyTk9OQ1lqZEdPcTVsZWc');
var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
var myStringArray = sheet.getRange('A1:A50');
```

Comment: Edits to questions should only be made to improve the quality of the question. Your "answer found" edit appears to have little to do with your original question - it looks like the answer to another question. If you think you have an answer to your own question, great - add it as an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With

```
var myStringArray = sheet.getRange('A1:A50');
```

You have retrieved the range object.

To return the values in the range object as an array

```
var myStringArray = sheet.getRange('A1:A50').getValues();
```

Even though there is only one row in your array it will be returned as 2 dimensions and will have to be addressed as:

```
var r = 5; // sixth row as arrays are zero based
var c = 0; // column A or first column in array
return myStringArray[r][c]
```

variables r & c are not necessary. For explanation only.